# Prevent an Android service from getting destroyed after an unbind

Tags: android, android-service

I have a scenario where an activity starts a service by invoking the `startService` method: both the `Activity` and the `Service` are in the same package. Then the service, according to its configuration parameters, could launch an activity (Let's call it `ExternalActivity`) contained in a different package: this activity bind the service through `bindService`; once this activity has finished its tasks, it calls the `unbindService` method as follows...

```
// method of ExternalActivity
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unbindService(...);
}
```

As a consequence, the service is also destroyed.
Is there the possibility of avoiding the destruction of the service?

Comment: According to the [dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html): **A bound service is destroyed once all clients unbind, unless the service was also started.** Do you manually stop it in onUnbind() method?

Comment: @yorkw: my service does not implement `onUnbind` method.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> As a consequence, the service is also destroyed.

As yorkw explained, a service is destroyed only when *both* of the following are true:

1. All calls to `bindService()` have been matched by corresponding calls to `unbindService()`.
2. *If* somebody called `startService()`, somebody also called `stopService()` or the service called `stopSelf()`.

> Is there the possibility of avoiding the destruction of the service?

Find a better time to call `stopService()` or `stopSelf()`, whichever of those you are using.

Comment: I manually call `stopService` only when I click on a button of the activity which start the service. Nevertheless, the service is destroyed when `ExternalActivity` (the only application that bind the service) calls `unbindService`.

Comment: @enzom83: So, it is working correctly. Great! It is very important for your service to be shut down when it is no longer needed. If the user specifically pressed a button to say they no longer need the service, please respect their wishes. Otherwise, they will attack you with task killers and force-stops from Settings, and you won't like that one bit.

Comment: I fixed the malfunctioning by overriding the `onStartCommand` method, so it now returns `START_STICKY`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't agree... Someone may need to keep service running after closing service configurator!

Comment: @FlashThunder - exactly. If app needs an ongoing serial (bluetooth) communication with a remote device, it should never destroy itself until explicitly asked by the user.

Comment: How about the `Context` from which the `Service` is attached?

Comment: @mr5: I am sorry, but I do not understand your question. You may wish to post a separate Stack Overflow question where you explain in greater detail what your concerns are.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there any difference between application's `Context` and activity's `Context`? If the answer is yes, I think I have already cleared my doubts because I'm getting a service connection leaked when I'm trying to bind from activity's context but not unbinding to it when transitioning from one activity to another (since I'm trying not to destroy the service). Anyway, I have already fixed my issue. I just want a confirmation from others :)

Comment: @mr5: "Is there any difference between application's Context and activity's Context?" -- yes. "'getting a service connection leaked when I'm trying to bind from activity's context but not unbinding to it when transitioning from one activity to another" -- yes, that's a problem. Bind from the application `Context` in both places, and you will avoid this issue.

Comment: Does context destruction unbind service automatically or I MUST explicitly call `unbindService()`?

Comment: @Eido95: I always explicitly unbind, mostly because I only want to unbind when the activity is being destroyed "for realz", not just due to a configuration change.

Comment: @CommonsWare, would you consider NOT using `unbindService()` as an act for keeping the service indefinitely run in the background as bad practice in contrast for using `startService()` (which declares that the service intended to indefinitely run in the background) ?

Comment: @Eido95: I doubt that it will have the desired effect.